# Hangfire: Too many connections opened on postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, hangfire

I'm trying to set up Hangfire (version 1.7.3) on a C# API with Postgres, but I need to limit the number of connections Hangfire uses in Postgres.

```
app.UseHangfireServer(config => {
    config.UseServer(2); //that option does't exist for postgres
});
```

Comment: So what is your question? You can restrict hangfire concurrency in the way you describe. What is the problem?

Comment: Which version of Hangfire.Postgres do you use? The last version fix an issue on connections leak.

Comment: Hanfire version is 1.7.3 and Postgres version is 11.5. I'm running APIs on digital ocean with postgres, but their limit postgres databases pools to 22 and Hangfire using almost all connections pools, something about 18 pools connection.

Comment: @LucasClazerPerussolo .Net connections are by default pooled. You can set max and min idle connections in the pool.

Answer (score 2):

Found proper solution:

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = 2 };
app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

Connections dropped to 6 from 20+ (crash on heroku).